# sql ssrs how to match variable to table parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report that requires a parameter which may have one value, or a collection of values (jurisdictions assigned to a district office).  I can't figure out how to ask sql if a particular value (a.jurisdiction) matched to a value contained in a parameter set up as a table.  I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @District INT = 1614 --Richmond D1
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20160101'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '20160731'


DECLARE @Jurisdiction TABLE(Location INT) --= 1223 --Richmond City --multiselect?
IF @District = 1614 --Richmond District 1
INSERT INTO @Jurisdiction Values (1223); --Richmond City
IF @District = 1632 --Newport News District 19
INSERT INTO @Jurisdiction Values (1203); --Newport News
IF @District = 1642 --Fairfax District 29
INSERT INTO @Jurisdiction Values (2568) --Fairfax City
,(1154) ,(1140) ,(1178) ,(1243) 
SELECT b.OffenderId
    , b.Sex
    , b.CurrentLocationId
    , b.MasterTermId
    , b.ReleaseDate
    , b.Jurisdiction
    , b.HomePlanAddress
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT o.OffenderId
            , o.CurrentLocationId
            , CASE WHEN o.GenderId = 12 THEN 'M'
                WHEN o.GenderId = 13 THEN 'F'
                ELSE 'Unknown' END AS Sex
            , mt.MasterTermId
            , t.TermId 
            , CASE WHEN t.GtrdApprovedDate IS NULL AND
            t.MprdApprovedDate IS NULL THEN '19000101'
        WHEN t.GtrdApprovedDate IS NULL THEN t.MprdApprovedDate
        WHEN t.MprdApprovedDate IS NULL THEN t.GtrdApprovedDate
        WHEN t.MprdApprovedDate < t.GtrdApprovedDate THEN 
                          t.MprdApprovedDate
        ELSE t.GtrdApprovedDate END AS ReleaseDate
        , j.HomePlanAddress
        , j.Jurisdiction    
        FROM ind.Offender AS o
        INNER JOIN (SELECT oa.OffenderId
        , oa.AddressId
        , LTRIM(COALESCE(CAST(a.StreetNumber AS 
                    VARCHAR(10)),' ') + COALESCE(a.StreetNumberSuffix
                    + ' ',' '  
                    + COALESCE(a.StreetName + ',','') + COALESCE(' ' 
                    + a.AppartmentNumber + ',','')
        + l.LocationName + ',' + 'VA ' + COALESCE
                    (a.ZipCode,'')) AS HomePlanAddress
        , j.LocationName AS Jurisdiction
    FROM ind.Offender_Address AS oa
        INNER JOIN ref.Address AS a ON oa.AddressId =
                              a.AddressId
    LEFT JOIN ref.Location AS l ON a.CountyId = l.LocationId
    INNER JOIN ref.Location AS j ON a.JurisdictionId = j.LocationId
    WHERE a.StateId = 1047
    AND EXISTS (SELECT a.JurisdictionId FROM @Jurisdiction)
    --AND a.JurisdictionId IN (@Jurisdiction) --
    AND oa.AddressTypeId = 5 --Proposed
    AND oa.EndDate IS NULL) AS j ON o.OffenderId = j.OffenderId
INNER JOIN scl.MasterTerm AS mt ON o.OffenderId = mt.OffenderId
LEFT JOIN scl.Term AS t ON mt.MasterTermId = t.MasterTermId
WHERE o.CurrentLocationId IS NOT NULL
AND t.TermStatusId <> 631) AS b --Inactive
WHERE b.ReleaseDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

I've tried to find solutions, but most of them refer to using stored procedures, which I can't use in our environment.  I tried the EXISTS option on one answer I found, but it gives me all locations, not just the ones in the parameter. Any suggestions?

The reference to the answer SSRS Multiple Value parameter filter based on dataset doesn't seem to address the fact that the District parameter has no one-on-one match to the values used for Jurisdiction. But it gives me something to work on and play around with.

Comment: How is `@Jurisdiction` being populated? Is it multi value parameter? Did you try using `where like @Jurisdiction`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Multiple Value parameter filter based on dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168471/ssrs-multiple-value-parameter-filter-based-on-dataset)

Comment: Jurisdiction is populated at the very top of the code I enclosed. It's a table based on the value of the District parameter which is the option the user selects when running the form.  There's not a one-to-one match between District and Jurisdiction, I can't build another dataset (company restrictions), and the user wouldn't know which jurisdictions match their district.  The possible duplicate question doesn't seem to fit my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why

```
AND a.JurisdictionId IN (@Jurisdiction)
```

doesn't work for you. As far as I can tell it should.

You can try adding the **Filter** to the SSRS **dataset** instead of inside the query. Choose your **Jurisdiction** for the **Expression** and your **Jurisdiction Parameter** as the **value**.

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a try when I go in Monday. Thanks.