# SSRS : Filter Duplicate Values simple no multiple values allowed

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to create a parameter for date which filters the duplicate date values so that dropdown shows only distinct values. I have tried the steps mentioned in the following link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2011/04/27/walkthrough-how-to-get-distinct-values-of-a-column-of-a-sharepoint-list-using-sql-server-reporting-services/ but its only for mutiple select not for single select. Can anyone suggest steps and code for single select ? 
Also here is the same code as mentioned in the link I have tried :-

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(parameter As Parameter) As String()

Dim items As Object() = parameter.Value
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0

For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
Continue For
End If

items(k) = items(i)
k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)

Return unique
End Function
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with sharepoint?

Comment: @scsimon   No but its more of same steps..Its SSRS report with no sharepoint but steps for removing duplicates remains the same

Comment: What's the source of your parameter? If it's `SQL Server` you can just use a `DISTINCT` to get unique values..

Comment: @NickyvV Its SQL Server but I cant use query while creating parameter in ssrs or i dont know how to use distinct in parameter expression

Comment: Yes you can... and that's why I asked if this was sharepoint related

Comment: @NickyvV what changes in the code i should make for single values... I dont know much of VB coding.

Comment: @scsimon can you give me an expression. I tried Select distinct columnname from tablename. it didnt worked. expression box was not closing

Comment: Take a look over here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168471/ssrs-multiple-value-parameter-filter-based-on-dataset

Comment: Please update your post with the code you've tried.

Comment: @sepupic I have posted a link which has code

Comment: @sepupic added code.

Comment: @NickyvV thats a good hack..I will try it.

Comment: OMG! If you don't use sharepoint for what reason do you use vb script? From WHAT do you want to get unique values, from table?

Comment: @sepupic  I want to get it for parameter that are being used as filter in ssrs report.

Comment: From WHAT do you want to get it for parameter?

Comment: WHAT is the source of your dates?

Comment: @sepupic I did it with NickyvV way..Its sort of hacky but still clean!

Comment: @NickyvV It worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing hacky in this, in that post the table is the datasource, and even if I asked you 3 times you did not answered that you get your values from a table

Comment: @sepupic sorry but i have already answered in one of my comment its coming from table.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I just added a new data set for the date selecting distinct values using query :-

```
Select Distinct  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RunDate,103) AS  RunDate
from Index
```

And used the above data set for selecting Run Date column as parameter.